# Showing $\int\limits_0^{\pi}\log(\sin(\theta))d\theta = -\pi \log(2)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals

I have to show that

$$
\int_{0}^{\pi}\log(\sin(\theta))d\theta = -\pi \log(2)
$$

This is a problem from the complex & real analysis qualifying exam.

This problem is maybe solvable by usual integration techniques but I strongly believe that they want us to prove it using complex analysis methods. Any approach will be appreciated.

I already tried with no luck:

1. $u = \sin(\theta)$
2. $u = \theta - \frac{\pi}{2}$
3. $\sin(\theta) = \frac{e^{i\theta} - e^{-i\theta}}{2i}$ and define a semi-circle that avoids $\{0\}$ and define a branch outsite that region (for example in the III or IV quadrants).

Comment: Perhaps you mean the integral $$\int\limits_0^{\pi}\log(\sin(\theta))d\theta = -\pi \log(2)$$, otherwise your conjectured solution is incorrect.

Comment: You are right. I fixed the problem.

Comment: Approach three works by employing Euler's identiy.Then integrate over an rectangle in the upper half  of the complex plane with one side equal to the interval $(0,\pi/2)$. Let the length of the sides paralell to the complex plane go to infinity.

Comment: @tired Can you post a detailed answer below? or you are just too tired?  lol

Comment: @RichardClare yepp :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set $I = \displaystyle \int_0^{\pi/2}\log(\cos(x))dx$. Then

\begin{align}
I &= \displaystyle \frac{I+I}{2}\\ \\
&=\frac12\int_0^{\pi/2}\log\big(\sin(x))+\log(\cos(x)\big)dx \\ \\
&=\frac12\int_0^{\pi/2}\log\big(\sin(x)\cos(x)\big)dx\\ \\
&=\frac12\int_0^{\pi/2}\log\left(\frac12\sin(2x)\right)dx\\ \\
&=\frac\pi4 \log\left(\frac12\right) + \frac12\int_0^{\pi /2}\log(\sin(2x))dx\\ \\
&=\frac\pi4 \log\left(\frac12\right) + \frac I4 + \frac14\int_0^{\pi/2}\log(\cos(x))dx\\ \\
&=\frac\pi4 \log\left(\frac12\right) + \frac I4 + \frac I4\\ \\
&= \frac\pi4 \log\left(\frac12\right) + \frac I2.
\end{align}

Hence $I = \displaystyle \frac\pi 2 \log\left(\frac12\right).$

Edit: perhaps my choice to attack the problem as I did is unclear. Here's maybe a little intuition for why the integrals for $\log\circ \sin$ and $\log \circ \cos$ should be equal on this interval. Look at the Riemann sums. Take a rectangle on the left half, while looking at $\log \circ \cos$. It will correspond exactly to a rectangle on the right half of the interval for $\log \circ \sin$ by the symmetry of $\sin$ and $\cos$ about $\displaystyle \frac\pi4$.

Here is a full calculation, with all the gory details.

Set $u= x-\displaystyle\frac\pi2$, so $\cos(x) = -\sin(u)$. Then we have 
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\log(\cos(x))dx = \int_{-\pi /2}^0 \log(-\sin(u))du = \int_{-\pi/2}^0 \log(\sin(-u))du $$
$$= \int_{\pi/2}^0 \log(\sin(u))(-du) = \int_0^{\pi/2}\log(\sin(u))du$$
as desired.

Comment: How did you come with the idea that the integral of $\log(\cos(x))$ and $\log(\sin(x))$ are equal in $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$ ?

Comment: Answer confirmed by *Mathematica*.

Comment: This is not complex analysis.

Comment: @Richard use a change of variables. Note that $\ln \sin \theta=\ln \cos\left(\frac\pi2-\theta\right)$ and then use $\phi=\frac\pi2-\theta$.

Comment: @ElliotG Thank you so much. I had neither the heart nor the time to fix my formatting when I originally posted.

Comment: @RichardClare See my edit for some intuition, but also see Elliot's comment.

Comment: @DavidBowman I already figured out that by my self when I was solving the integral again by myself. Thank you anyway for your answer.